# How to load an .exe when a .txt document contains a specific word/phrase

Tags: batch-file, text

I am trying to get a batch script to load a .exe when a file called "Week.txt" contains "Week B", but I can't seem to get it to work. The following is seems to work but when I add in a line to test if it does I doesn't work properly. I am still writing the .exe but it will load a GUI timer.

Non-test code

```
:repeat
for /f %%a in (Week.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="Week B" goto execute
for /f %%a in (Week.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="Week A" goto repeat
:execute
```

Test Code

```
:repeat
for /f %%a in (Week.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="Week B" goto execute

for /f %%a in (Week.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="Week A" goto repeat
msg * Hello Test Bad
:execute
msg * Hello Test Good
```

If someone can tell/show me where I have gone wrong that would be good.
Thanks.

Comment: What should it do if week.txt does not contain `Week B` nor `Week A`?

Comment: What is the format of Week.txt? Can you post a small snip of it?

Comment: The text document is a result of a input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:start
SET "$t=0"
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('type Week.txt ^| find /i "Week A"') do (
set "$t=1"
call:execute)
if !$t! equ 0 (
echo nothing found
>nul PING localhost -n 2 -w 1000
goto:start)

exit/b

:execute
echo running the exe
::Here you put the name of your .exe
```

I put a tempo     `>nul PING localhost -n 2 -w 1000` between the iteration to decrease the processor's need.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `for`:

```
:repeat
 timeout 1>nul
 find /i "Week B" week.txt && goto execute || goto repeat
:execute
```

search for "Week B" in week.txt; if found (`&&`) do something, if not found (`||`) do another thing

If you program a loop that needs nearly no time, it's a good idea to implement a wait-cycle (here `timeout`), otherwise the loop will run the CPU to it's limits.